# How to resolve incoherence between question and answer

Tags: discussion

## The problem

I have just come across a perfect example of a phenomenon I see from time to time and am unsure of how to deal with. The situation is a question with has an accepted answer. The problem is that sometimes a question appears that explicitly includes or requests some erroneous piece of information. Then an answer is provided that ignores this part of the question, but gets at the heart of the matter. Now we have a good question/answer providing relevant information, but a discrepancy between what is asked and what is actually answered.

## An example

This [particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950704/how-to-count-the-no-of-open-brackets-and-no-of-close-brackets) / [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950704/how-to-count-the-no-of-open-brackets-and-no-of-close-brackets/13950993#13950993) is what got me thinking. In this particular case with lots of up-votes, and a bounty (it's "high-profile").

The poster asks for a `regex` way to count the number of parentheses pairs in a string of javascript and the validity of the string.

The answer provides a method for testing whether a string of javascript code is valid (without regexes or balancing parens).

Now there is some sort of imbalance here. Someone may find this question hoping for information about how to balance parens (or other open/close punctuation) via regexes. Unfortunately, the accepted answer has *nothing* to do with this case, although it is part of the question.

The answer does seem to satisfy what the OP *wanted*, but not exactly what he/she *asked*. So I feel that some sort of action needs to be taken, but I'm not sure what exactly.

## Considerations

My gut reaction is to edit the **question** to match the **answer**. The answer is appropriate for what was desired, the fact that the OP added some irrelevant constraints and tags can be at the source fixed. This seems like a pretty radical course of action. This may also inhibit other users thinking of the same (erroneous) approach from finding the solution.

I've also considered flagging the question or answer, but I don't think that's appropriate here, as everything complies with the *spirit* of SO.

Probably the simplest approach is to edit the answer to include something about the erroneous part of the question, citing that it may be unneccessary to do what the OP is requesting, and that this method is simpler/more direct.

The most time-consuming and potentially rewarding course of action may be to write a completely new answer, incorporating what's good about the accepted answer and adding new information about the "extra" requests in the question. While potentially rewarding and enriching for SO, this also feels a bit like a waste of time, as you're answering what not *really* being asked.

Of course, this is really just an enumeration of the different ways you can deal with things on SO, and I'm really interested in what the community thinks about how this scenario is best handled :)

Comment: The asker does not seem to have done a very good job of expressing their question. They might need a bit of help. In fact, being so long after the fact, they probably don't even care if you butcher their question.

Comment: This is dangerous.  The value-add of such an answer is that it found a very unexpected solution to the OP's problem.  Odds are that after editing the question, the answer becomes trivial and obvious and loses all value to programmers that were stumped the same way as the OP was.  Keep in mind that other programmers never google an answer, only ever a question.  Albeit that [regex] questions never google well and seem to be asked repeatedly.

Comment: So is there nothing to be done here, just "meh, close enough"? I really want to know if some harmony can be achieved between Q&A…

Comment: A lot of people ask, "How can I use regex to foo the bar?" and quite often the best answer is, "Don't. There are better tools than regex for fooing the bar." If you remove "regex" from the question, other people who have the same misguided notion that regex is the solution to everything may not find it.

Comment: Yes, people try to incorrectly use regexes all the time, that's actually one of the unfortunate things I see in this particular thread. There's an interesting regex question (How can I find sets of parens?) that goes unanswered.

Comment: Agree with Hans: other people will make the same mistake the initial asker did, and you want them to search for the problem as they see it and find the alternative way of thinking about it. I'd say suggests it could help to *add* to the question ("My end goal is to catch invalid JavaScript") or make the answer note that it took on a slightly different question ("It looks like you're checking for valid JS, and there are better ways to do that than regular expressions..." rather than just jumping into code).

Comment: Dunno what's most in line with SO norms about not changing intent, etc.--that just seems like a useful approach for making questions/answers both clear and useful to similarly confused searchers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't edit either; what happened here is that the asker 'helpfully' put extra info in the question, turning it into a 'wrong' question. Unfortunately a lot of other people will be asking the wrong question as well. Therefore, they will Google it and get the right answer.

It's like the other day I asked the mechanic if he wouldn't just top off my transmission fluid, as it was low. He said, it doesn't dissipate, there's got to be a leak. And there was.

Too many people think regular expressions are just topping off the fluids. "I need a regex to validate an email address". Fight it! And a question like this is good bait.

I note the focus here is on this one question and regexes. There will be other similar things (overly qualifying what they expect the answer to be), but also, other incongruences.

But this is organic Q&A self-development at its best. People will ask Google. Stack Overflow will attract it. And they will find their answers.

### Edit:

Note Paul Crovella's comment to the original question about how this is an XY problem, I found that helpful.

Comment: Google the wrong question and get the right answer? Zombie Charles Babbage is coming for you.

Comment: If they add any information that makes it a completely different (or incorrect) question, I always suggest an edit to roll-back to a point the question didn't suck. If I can't do that I always flag for moderator attention who will normally roll the question back- I mean 'normally' as I've had 20 moderator flags like this and only two were rejected.

Comment: I think adding some info to the answer like "regex is not the best solution" would still be good.

Comment: @JonSurrell - Agreed, that would be a very good edit, it makes an important point. I guess I was being a little over-strict suggesting not to touch anything!